# What's causing "Can't resolve 'react-big-calendar/lib/sass/styles'" error while using react-big-calendar with sass on Next.js?

Tags: next.js, sass, react-big-calendar

i import 'react-big-calendar/lib/sass/styles' cause im using sass in my project but it says
**
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-big-calendar/lib/sass/styles'**

```
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Toolbar } from './Toolbar';
import 'moment/locale/ja';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/sass/styles';

moment.locale('ja');

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

const formats = {
  dateFormat: 'D',
  dayFormat: 'D(ddd)',
  monthHeaderFormat: 'YYYY年M月',
  dayHeaderFormat: 'M月D日(ddd)',
  dayRangeHeaderFormat: ({ start, end }: { start: Date; end: Date }) =>
    `${moment(start).format('YYYY年M月')} - ${moment(end).format('YYYY年M月')}`,
};

export const MyCalendar = () => (
  <Calendar
    // className={styles.calendar}
    style={{ height: '80vh' }}
    localizer={localizer}
    views={['month']}
    formats={formats}
    components={{
      toolbar: Toolbar,
    }}
  />
);
```

how do i fix this?

i tried to place @import 'react-big-calendar/lib/sass/styles'; in styles.module.scss but it didnt work and i cant style my calendar

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have figured it out yet by the time I'm typing. But just in case, try this `import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';`

You can find relevant information in their github repo page.

Good luck!